# Ember-charts resulting in Could not find property 'pie-chart' on object

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-charts

I'm using Ember.js and my bower.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "stats-front-end",
  "dependencies": {
    "handlebars": "~1.3.0",
    "jquery": "~2.1.1",
    "ember": "1.8.1",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.12",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.10",
    "loader.js": "stefanpenner/loader.js#1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-shims": "stefanpenner/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "rwjblue/ember-cli-test-loader#0.0.4",
    "ember-load-initializers": "stefanpenner/ember-load-initializers#0.0.2",
    "ember-qunit": "0.1.8",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.4",
    "qunit": "~1.15.0",
    "ember-charts": "~0.3.0"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to display a pie chart in my `app/templates/languages/index.hbs` view as shown [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rekawobugu/1/edit?html,js,output).  The `app/templates/languages/index.hbs` is currently this:

```
<ul>
  {{#each}}
    <li> {{name}} {{occurences}}</li>
  {{else}}
    <li>No language found.</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

<div class="chart-container">
  {{pie-chart data=content}}
</div>
```

If I remove the chart my `#each` block renders fine (pulling from ember-data).  However, when I use the controller found at: `app/controllers/languages/index.js` to decorate the view, I get nothing, even without pulling from ember data.

**app/controllers/languages/index.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  content: [
    {
      "label": "Equity",
      "value": 12935781.176999997
    },
    {
      "label": "Real Assets",
      "value": 10475849.276172025
    },
    {
      "label": "Fixed Income",
      "value": 8231078.16438347
    },
    {
      "label": "Cash & Cash Equivalent",
      "value": 5403418.115000006
    },
    {
      "label": "Hedge Fund",
      "value": 1621341.246006786
    },
    {
      "label": "Private Equity",
      "value": 1574677.59
    }
    ]
});
```

Console reads:

```
Uncaught Error: <stats-front-end@view:default::ember426> Handlebars error: Could not find property 'pie-chart' on object <stats-front-end@controller:languages/index::ember418>.
```

I've tried variations of syntax to get the pie-chart into the view without success.  Ideally I'd like to build the pie-chart from what I have in ember-data but at this point just getting something to render would be nice.

The project is open source and found [here](https://github.com/allcentury/stats-front-end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now Ember-Charts code is not included in your built `dist\assets\vendor.js` file. Installing bower packages in ember-cli doesn't mean that the installed package's code will be included in your app.
Ember simply could not find the `pie-chart` component so it's looking up `pie-chart` as a property on your controller.
You should add to your `Brocfile.js` the following code:

```js
app.import('bower_components/ember-charts/dist/ember-charts.js');
app.import('bower_components/ember-charts/dist/ember-charts.css');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `content` of a controller is usually set in a `route`, in the `#setupController` method. Since you're returning `this.store.find('language')` from your `languages/index` route, Ember is going to try to set that on the content of your controller. So don't set it manually.

So first, try to set that array on some other property, say `data`, and see if you can even display it in your template (without using the `{{pie-chart}}` component). Then try to get it to work with the component.

One last point, you should start using the explicit form of the `each` helper (e.g. `each x in controller` instead of `each`), as the implicit one will be deprecated soon.

Finally try to use components instead of controllers. For example, you could make your `ArrayController` a `LanguageListComponent` (and then you could move the pie chart data there).

Comment: Thanks Sam!  If I remove `{{pie-chart data=content}}` the page loads fine with the data stored in my model (not the manual one I referenced above).  Ramy's answer has helped a bit but still stuck on the same issue, even though I see `Ember.Handlebars.helper('pie-chart', Ember.Charts.PieComponent);` in my `vendor.js`